# [warning]Can\'t find loc string for key: CorrelationIdForARM

Tags: azure, warnings, azure-pipelines, azure-resource-manager

I designed a CI/CD pipeline to deploy an ARM Template from github to create an instance of api management in my resource group using the ARM Template.

In my release logs, I am constantly getting this warning "Can\'t find loc string for key: CorrelationIdForARM" which is slowing down the process. Although after taking a long time the resource is successfully created still the release appears as failed.

[logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j627I.png)

Comment: I googled the message, seems like a missing localisation, affects a lot of tasks. We get the same ones.

Comment: This started appearching in a lot of our pipelines as well. Should be caused by a recent change in the last 1-2 months on Microsoft side.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There appears to have been some change introduced by Microsoft that started prompting these warnings when using App Service-related steps.  In my case, we use separate steps to first stop, deploy, then start an App Service, and each one of those steps contains at least five of these "warnings."  We don't do anything advanced either, just simple deployments; no slot swaps, no ARM templates, just .NET Core code deployment.

Microsoft appears to have heard our complaints and already reported "we have merged the fix for the issue."  Not sure how long until we will see that fix implemented however, as it appears to be more of an annoyance rather than something that breaks builds.

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/859513/azure-app-service-manage-warnings.html

Answer (score 3):

They just announced the solution for this is being deployed and should be fixed for all accounts by the end of the week:

> Hi, the fix for CorrelationIdForARM warning is already merged and is under deployment. It should reach all the accounts by the end of this week. Thankyou for your patience.

Source: https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/issues/11996

Answer (score 1):

still getting this error, its getting worse now. Agent Jobs just hanging now.
"Can\'t find loc string for key: CorrelationIdForARM"